# Why do time adverbials like "yesterday" have a different distribution than adverbials like "always?"

Tags: semantics, grammar

Consider these two sentences below, which employ some kind of temporal adverbial / adjunct.

(I) **Yesterday** John won the Turkey Raffle.
(II) John **always** wins the Turkey Raffle.

My question is, why is the sentence below ungrammatical?

(III) *John **yesterday** won the Turkey Raffle.

Other examples:

(IV) Mary has **always** vacationed in Brazil for the Thanksgiving Holiday.

(V) *Mary has **this year** vacationed in Brazil.

Also:

(VI) ***Always** Mary has vacationed in Brazil for the Thanksgiving Holiday.

I suspect my assumption that words like **always** have the same (lexical/semantic) analysis as phrases like **yesterday** or **this year** is incorrect.  Yet I don't see any strong reason why sentences like (III) and (V) *have* to be ungrammatical, other than a quirk of English.

Comment: III is pretty bad, but V is okay, if you put in some big pauses around it. Mary has, this year, vacationed in Brazil.

Comment: Without those pauses though it should still be bad (e.g. same intonation as (IV))?  Thanks for verifying (III); I had repeated it so much it started to sound fine.

Comment: Perhaps III would be okay with some big pauses too. Whether bad equals ungrammatical though is hard to say...

Comment: Both still sound very marked compared to the "always" examples.  My question is why is that the case.  Note other adverbs are fine in those positions, e.g. "John amazingly won the Turkey Raffle."

Comment: I don't think a "why" question such as this one can be answered. I agree with your concluding remark about this being a quirk of English. I speak a couple of Indian languages, and in both, "always" and "yesterday" can occur in either of the positions you described. I don't think the phenomenon you described pertains to *the nature of language* like adjective ordering does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many differences between the time adverbials (like **yesterday**) and "adverbials like **always**".

Time adverbials are very much like place adverbials (**home**, **there**), both of them specify a particular *location*, in time or in space. Also, both of them are not very specific, we can substitute each of them with lots of synonyms, I can say "**Last year** I went to the sea." or I can say just the same by "**Last summer** I went to the sea." or by "**Last August** I went to the sea." or by "**On August 10** I went to the sea." And the same goes about the place adverbials, **on my sofa** can be substituted by **in my room** or by **at home**. Note, none of those substitutions won't change practically anything.

"Adverbials like **always**" are different. First, their number is limited, they are a closed group, while time and place adverbials are innumerable, they are an open group. Then, they have no synonyms, **always** looks very much similar to **often**, still the difference is obvious. These adverbs are very closely connected with verbs, they actually change the meaning of verbs, there is a huge difference between "John comes to us." and "John **always** comes to us.", the periodicity of the action is absolutely different in the two sentences, but if we take "John came to us **last Tuesday**." and "John came to us **last Wednesday**." there is no difference in the manner the action happened, only its location in time is different. It is this interconnection with verbs that makes it possible for them to occupy the place immediately before the predicate.

Comment: Yes. _Always_ is a quantifier, and _yesterday_ isn't. That's a ***big*** difference. Adverbs are anything that behaves like an adverb (niching in various places, indicating oblique relations); but some are not just adverbs but Operators, with superpowers. Negatives, Quantifiers, and Modals are the Big Three Operators; whenever a sentence has one of them, beware. When it has two or more, find shelter.

Comment: @jlawler **yesterday** is an existential quantifier in Davidsonian semantics: it says that there exists a date on which the event took place, and that the date was one less than the utterance date.

Comment: No such assertion necessary; the diurnal cycle is a granted (i.e, presupposed) in natural language. It's not necessary to use lambdafication except when nominalizing, and it's optional there.

Comment: @jlawler such lambdafication even cleans up tense and aspect, so I side with those who treat time as a fundamental aspect of language.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion, but of evidence. Except in philosophy and mathematics, of course. Any talk of time is metaphoric and not perceptual, and metaphor is always alogical. Natural language blithely goes on to multi-order calculi and non-representational meanings, without benefit of clergy.

Comment: @jlawler I'll put it in another way. You said **always** is a quantifier. Quantifier over what? **Yesterday** is a quantifier over the exact same thing, except that instead of being a universal quantifier like **always**, **yesterday** is an existential quantifier.

Comment: It is if you say it is; it's your language.

Comment: @jlawler so in your language, what does **always** quantify over?